# Parsing exception for MultiLineString field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index named "test" with type "Test" and it contains a field named "path" of type geo_shape. The mapping for the "path" field is as below.

```
"path" : { "type" : "geo_shape", "tree" : "quadtree", "precision" : "1m" }
```

The index is created and the data is being indexed into all the fields except "path". When I tried to update a row with "path" value it is throwing an exception. Please find below the code and exception I tried.

Code to insert the line::

```
curl -XPOST 'http://192.168.22.10:9200/test/Test/road4/_update' -d '{
"doc" : {
    "path" : {"type" : "multilinestring", "coordinates" : [[-123.04884393678275, 49.23705680269003], [-123.04879834103596, 49.23159242031221], [-123.04880573577739, 49.23116567921752], [-123.04668158540538, 49.290719445433304], [-123.0466780844126, 49.291215069306], [-123.04670614567429, 49.27962543136022], [-123.04670642699772, 49.279082952438834], [-123.04936250390882, 49.27579927483156], [-123.04937093312175, 49.27538530710557], [-123.05055562575079, 49.21895094399069], [-123.05055807601889, 49.21846682583291], [-123.04670649653067, 49.27867636307187], [-123.04670701928822, 49.278269503692414], [-123.04880573577739, 49.23116567921752], [-123.0488097592407, 49.23076600972447], [-123.04962419053852, 49.248828838567086], [-123.04963156425279, 49.24793363261724], [-123.05047029168206, 49.221885631113466], [-123.05051215363366, 49.22107152666596], [-123.04963893290395, 49.24545136109131], [-123.04964184010389, 49.244621898312424]]}}}'
```

Exception got::

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse [linePath]]; nested: NullPointerException; ","status":400}
```

It would be a great help, if someone can look into this and help..

Thanks in advance,
SantoshM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three arrays for `multilinestring`, like this

```
curl -XPOST 'http://192.168.22.10:9200/test/Test/road4/_update' -d '{
"doc" : {
    "path" : {"type" : "multilinestring", "coordinates" : [[[-123.04884393678275, 49.23705680269003], [-123.04879834103596, 49.23159242031221], [-123.04880573577739, 49.23116567921752], [-123.04668158540538, 49.290719445433304], [-123.0466780844126, 49.291215069306], [-123.04670614567429, 49.27962543136022], [-123.04670642699772, 49.279082952438834], [-123.04936250390882, 49.27579927483156], [-123.04937093312175, 49.27538530710557], [-123.05055562575079, 49.21895094399069], [-123.05055807601889, 49.21846682583291], [-123.04670649653067, 49.27867636307187], [-123.04670701928822, 49.278269503692414], [-123.04880573577739, 49.23116567921752], [-123.0488097592407, 49.23076600972447], [-123.04962419053852, 49.248828838567086], [-123.04963156425279, 49.24793363261724], [-123.05047029168206, 49.221885631113466], [-123.05051215363366, 49.22107152666596], [-123.04963893290395, 49.24545136109131], [-123.04964184010389, 49.244621898312424]]]}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, got the error in my code.

My format for multilinestring input is incorrect. It should be like below.

```
{
  "location" : {
    "type" : "multilinestring",
    "coordinates" : [
        [ [102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0] ],
        [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0] ],
        [ [100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8] ]
    ]
   }
}
```

For the above code, I should change the type from "multilinestring" to "linestring" or I should change my input to above format.

Thanks.